# Reducing nested schema using TypeScript static typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, static-typing

Recently I've stuck on complicated task, being almost a challenge. And to solve it, you only need to make a reducing of the original data using static typing (TypeScript).

#### Input

```js
{
  schemaName: 'foo',
  def: Foo,
  struct: {
    field1: string,
    field2: {
      objectKey: number,
    },
    field3: {
      __ref: true,
      schema: {
        schemaName: 'bar',
        def: Bar,
        struct: {
          field4: number,
          field5: {
            __ref: true,
            schema: {
              schemaName: 'baz',
              def: Baz,
              struct: {
                field6: string,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    field7: {
      __ref: true,
      schema: {
        schemaName: 'qux',
        def: Qux,
        struct: {
          field8: boolean,
        }
      },
    },
  },
}
```

#### Output

And the task is to transform this structure into the following:

```js
type SchemaReduced = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
  baz: Baz,
  qux: Qux,
};
```

#### My attempt

```js
type FilterReferences<U> = U extends {__ref: true} ? U : never;
type ExtractNestedSchemas<S extends Schema<any, any, any>> = FilterReferences<S['struct'][keyof S['struct']]>['schema'];

type ReduceSchema<S extends Schema<any, any, any>> = {
  [name in S['schemaName']]: S['def']
} & {
  [name in ExtractNestedSchemas<S>['schemaName']]: ExtractNestedSchemas<S>['def']
} & {
  [name in ExtractNestedSchemas<ExtractNestedSchemas<S>>['schemaName']]: ExtractNestedSchemas<ExtractNestedSchemas<S>>['def']
};
```

```js
type testReducer = {
    foo: Foo;
} & {
    bar: Bar | Qux;
    qux: Bar | Qux;
} & {}
```

In the attached playground, I tried to do at least something to solve it, but attempts were in vain. Main problems:

- Nesting can be of any depth, but I never came up with recursive Reduce.
- `{baz: Baz}` is missing. But if you drop `field7`, `& {baz: Baz}` should appear. This is a bug.
- Instead of the desired `{bar: Bar, qux: Qux}` I'm getting `{bar: Bar | Qux, qux: Bar | Qux}`.

This is not someone else's challenge, the task is mine. How can I solve it?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=98&ssc=20&pln=98&pc=32#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgUQI4FcCGAbANCgDzAFMBjeAXzgDMoIQ4ByAARgE8SBaUgCx22IA7AObEAzgHp0MYNjGMAsAChl7EnABiECHAC8iCgG5VHYnABCmKHoPGlas5YBeNhEZPqAiugKv3K%201M4AGVeYhBMAB4AOUwQM2ICGCEAEzE4MRgoYBF8ABFiajhE5ME0uAgAIwArMhh8YKz0cmKk1PSq2vIAPldlOAywiNj4gC44EeJcfrgUwvGC6mmlAcyoZphxxvXyZf8PMwAlQuIoIVJiSODW0vLQnnCozEE2fGfXuHfu3v0EGYB9f5najjJpTGZiIaYLZ7OwHEJQ5AEOJgAQ2e6PSKMajaRj4LQQfB-FY0YDEbApACM4zWOWEywG1DJFIATONiQMBp06gBpYhscaCdAgSqnBlwCjipnklIAZnGx2op3OlwxESxlSseIsViJM0ZzJSABZBcLRVBxQaZQBWBUnM6CC5XKEazBObXOPUkzmkmUANhpWTplol33FFDDM2lFIA7HalQ6nWqoowMARtd4CF6fdGUgAOcaVbQCZ7hyNKCNwwLqZNIlECJFgZ5zFJ9EmQh7DOLEcbY3HiuYgzTacVrDbs-W%20inUjJB3KT3NsxCTrk1Xn800isWTyULw3y5fezmA4Gg9bgo%20rKETy%20cjuPSa9zVQPErzmD8aWC1v1ZNcg3n1AKnY1N3NEMgNzW1DyAoCT3mOAwXAmD7wiACYKAlDMEfJhNXdJD0I-HUnHw5C-02aD0Jg3MA1nbJ51vdDdwYwCmMoiUSNYliQ04q1YzQn04KHRC30w-jAMw7DUx8V9mMIzMSLHf8KPQ3MCzgIsIBLQQOLfHj2JmJj9mrBJkXAAQxDQLBsGAdgbEbOpIksnBnU7TA6zMqYEVc9zUWIRtm2IFJvirBwvMeY4UmaQK20ZbRxgJcVn0-XUZlw5LiJmNNxnk5QjIkAAqOBAWKkqSpCTTpGACBBCK0q6v%20OB8okZR4Q0WRkigRVlUdcRIgAVR%20OA%20pudpEEEs90GIKgAH4hrgQViAAN1OOxQqRLJMHIaJxGSFJkzEK4RrKdJk0id43heC62G%20Gw2uwDqusTXrggAbUYRSYEYABdF6AGt%20QgIpXvesjvq%207o3sw76QqCCKotO64SlG07zs%20S60euwaOTgF7BG7OAchCSGoUmMGtjewdvtyuAADIKNx-HCfWqBNpgbbMkC-argh96Se7MnCA2rads5qEDuCHnKa%206m6exhn4gJmrmdZ9ndq55XhY5vaxe5nmJP5r6vvGDW2ZF7XXIOk3VdFi3dYpwoqYrGH1GSTI4Yuax9Hd4gEcRUzfO6KsCtq%20qyoAFR2uAAGFMDEcQQ9DwFGuagJQtIWP4-0F6Zns8hHIwZzk29lJ8G933vP9gRvm6cUJAkOBWDEThEhIchm6gOgoBzogHKc7BIjLl1kxruB0EEX7BAgAB3QRywGOuG5gJuW7qdvO%2071uYHzqyB8C%20Gh6hEfBCW05yy%20wwgA).

Comment: Is this a task or a chalenge ? ))))))

Comment: @captain-yossarian, I hope naming the task as a challenge make it solved as soon as possible.